# Best way to cache parsed API data(from multiple APIs) in to core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Our app has lots of raw data points which we fetch from our server and save in core data.
App performs numerous operations on this raw data to show desired result to the user.
To achieve this, we save this raw data into our core data entities.
Complete process looks something like this:

```
API Response
   persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext() //in the same background queue
   context.perform {
       create NSManagedObject
       context.save()
   }
```

Now multiple APIs go in parallel for all kind of objects and all of them follow this same process.

Multiple APIs for same object also go in parallel. I sense an issue in this case.
Let’s say app receives 3 API responses in parallel for a particular object. That mean there will 3 background contexts created which will try to edit the same Entity.
1- Could this lead to a crash?
2- Is there a better way to handle it?

**EDIT:**
Reason why I ask this is because I have noticed following crash on newrelic and the stack trace always tracks down to context.save() of some save operation.
[image]

Comment: Each `perform` is on its own context queue, so there shouldn't have a crash issue. The potential issues are about: queue issue (if there are relation, make use the correct queue/context for each one), concurrency issue with override (if it's the same entity, there should be a unique id, who overwrite who? What's the merge policy?), refresh after merge context (do you get correctly the new data saved up to date?)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Larme.
- Could you please elaborate more on "queue issue".
- concurrency issue with override - We do have unique id setup and before saving we check if a new object needs to added or we should edit the old data.
- Refresh after merge context is working fine. We always get the latest data from the db post db save.

I have added more details in the main question for why I think my implementation is possibly causing a crash.